# Save all (non gdoc) revisions automatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I want to save all revisions from my pdf's, photos, and other non-GDoc files on my Google Drive. For this I want to use a Google Apps Script.

So how can I get all the *files* and their *revisions*?

Answer (score 1):

If you enable the **Drive API** from *Resources > Advanced Google Services*, you can use the [revisions](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/revisions) part of the API. For example:

```
var fileId = '<...id...>';

// Retrieve list of revisions - specify that the modifiedDate and download
// URL are required.
var response = Drive.Revisions.list(fileId, {fields:'items(downloadUrl,modifiedDate)'});
var revisions = JSON.parse(response);

var items = revisions.items;

// e.g. Inspect first item
var firstItem = items[0];
Logger.log(firstItem.downloadUrl);
Logger.log(firstItem.modifiedDate);

/*
https://...etc
2016-11-28T21:58:56.650Z
*/
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how do I get all the ID's from every File?

Comment: I can't specify every ID (I have like 100.000 files and counting)